# Jiggling ToggleSwitch on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, toggle

I just dropped in a toggle switch into my Windows Phone 7 project and if I go run it in the emulator or device, when you click to toggle, the switch jiggles up and down while the slider is moving, and then settles in the position where it first started.

Does anyone else get this behavior?

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch Header="ToggleSwitch" Height="111" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,397,0,0" Name="toggleSwitch1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" />
```

I haven't touched any of the attributes, left them just as they were when I dragged it in.

Comment: I found out what the issue was myself, I was in fact playing with animations, and by turning on TiltEffect.SetIsTiltEnabled(this, true) it made the control jiggle. Commenting out/removing that line fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already said it in your comment, but I do want to emphasize that this is due to the IsTiltEnabled property. If it is set to true an element will automatically "jiggle" when touched. The IsTiltEnabled effect is either set from XAML by

```
toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
```

or frome code-behind by

```
TiltEffect.SetIsTiltEnabled(this, true)
```

If you don't want any reaction to touching an element, make sure you turn this on off.